# Linq xml to object - How to populate a Collection<foo>

Tags: c#, linq

I need to read some xml and populate my class-structure. I would be so happy if somebody could provide me some neat code for that.

My simplified Class Structure:

```
public class Event
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("StartTimes")]
    public Collection<StartTime> StartTimeCollection;        
}

public class StartTime
{
    [XmlAttribute("Time")]
    public string Start { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Mon")]
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Tue")]
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Wed")]
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Thu")]
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Fri")]
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Sat")]
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Sun")]
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

xml looks like:

```
<Event Id="f7cfc3a5-5b1b-4941-8d7b-f8a4a71fa530">
  <StartTimes>
    <StartTime Time="19:00" Mon="false" Tue="false" Wed="false" Thu="false" Fri="true" Sat="false" Son="false"/>
  </StartTimes>
</Event>
```

And that's how my linq statement looks like:

```
from x in doc.Descendants("Event")
select new Event()
{
Id = x.Attribute("Id").Value,
StartTimeCollection = x.Descendants("StartTimes") ????????? <-- That's the tricky part for me
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Collection<T>` exposes a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) that takes an `IList<T>`, you can use [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) and write:

```
from x in doc.Descendants("Event")
select new Event() {
    Id = x.Attribute("Id").Value,
    StartTimeCollection = new Collection<StartTime>(
        x.Descendants("StartTimes").SelectMany(
            startTimes => startTimes.Elements("StartTime").Select(
                startTime => new StartTime() {
                    Start = startTime.Attribute("Time").Value,
                    Monday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Mon").Value),
                    Tuesday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Tue").Value),
                    Wednesday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Wed").Value),
                    Thursday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Thu").Value),
                    Friday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Fri").Value),
                    Saturday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Sat").Value),
                    Sunday = Boolean.Parse(startTime.Attribute("Son").Value)
                })).ToList())
}
```

Note that I used `Attribute("Son")` instead of `Attribute("Sun")` to initialize the `Sunday` property, since the attribute is named like that in your markup. It might be a typo, though.