# Linq xml to object - How to populate a Collection<string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Well, I recently asked a question on how to [populate a Collection with custom data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242736/linq-xml-to-object-how-to-populate-a-collectionfoo), but now I can not figure out how to populate a simple string Collection. Maybe somebody is willing to help me out.

My simplified Class Structure:

```
public class Accommodation
{
    [XmlElement("Attribute")]
    public Collection<string> Categories;        
}
```

xml looks like:

```
<Accommodation Id="f7cfc3a5-5b1b-4941-8d7b-f8a4a71fa530">
  <Categories>
    <Category Id=Time="1abc23"/>
    <Category Id=Time="2abc34"/>
  </Categories>
</Accommodation>
```

And that's how my linq statement looks at the moment (I need some help there:

```
from x in doc.Descendants("Accommodation")
select new Accommodation()
{
    Categories = new Collection<string>(x.Descendants("Categories").SelectMany(
    categories => categories.Elements("Category").Select(
    (string)x.Element("Categories").Element("Category").Attributes("Id")).ToList()))
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it like so, if somebody is curious. But I am sure that my solution involves probably more overhead than necessary.

```
 IEnumerable<Accommodation> temp = 
    (from x in doc.Descendants("Accommodation")
        select new Accommodation()
        {
            Categories = new Collection<string>(
                x.Descendants("Categories").SelectMany(categories 
                    => categories.Elements("Category").Select(category 
                        => category.Attribute("Id").Value ?? "")).ToList())
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want just this:

```
doc.Descendants("Accommodation")
   .Select(x => new Accomodation { Categories = 
                  x.Element("Categories")
                   .Elements("Category")
                   .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("id")).ToList() });
```

If `Accommodation` is the root tag of the XML it's even simpler:

```
var accomodation = new Accomodation
{
    Categories = doc.Root.Element("Categories")
                         .Elements("Category")
                         .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("id")).ToList()
}
```